# how can I make Css Shape like the first image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

[image]

I did the Second One using The CSS border-left and border-right and border-top property the code is below.

Now I want to make only bordered shape just like the first image.

```
.team-social-icons a {
    background: #3C4E62;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.team-social-icons a:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -8px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #3C4E62;
    content: "";
}
.team-social-icons a:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -8px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #3C4E62;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hexagon can be constructed with three rectangles, each with left- and right-border (but no top- and bottom-border), and each rotated at 60 degrees from the next. This can conveniently be done with one `:before` and `:after`.

To centre the contents, you can use `flex` with `align-items`/`justify-content`.

```css
.hexagon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 69px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 42px;
}
.hexagon:before, .hexagon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-left: 1px dashed black;
  border-right: 1px dashed black;
}
.hexagon:before {transform:rotate(60deg);}
.hexagon:after {transform:rotate(-60deg);}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"><b>1234</b>happy people</div>
```

Comment: Would you please tell me that how can I add the same border in the first image

Comment: `1px dashed black` probably?

Comment: border property doesn't work because I already use those for make shape

Comment: @Sharifur Well yes. See the edit I made to my answer, is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

First, so you're able to differentiate between border and background, make everything have the same background color, like in the first example. Then just do `border: 12px dotted white`

Of course, if you don't want the right side to be include in the border, just do `border-top` then `border-right` and so on

Comment: I did dotted because the first example looks like it was dotted. You can do solid if you wish

Comment: I this you don't understand the problem. I told that how can i use the border property in the after property
.team-social-icons a:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -8px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #3C4E62;
    content: "";
}.team-social-icons a:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -8px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #3C4E62;
    content: "";
}